# Discourage new users answering questions with accepted answers

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, new-users, late-answers

Quite often while using the new review feature, I find new users who answer questions that already have accepted answers.  As new users don't usually have any experience on how Stack Exchange sites work, they tend to answer the questions quite poorly.

What I am suggesting, is a popup message that will appear when they click to post an answer that will say something like:

> This question already has an accepted answer.  Only answer if you answer is more detailed than the one that is currently accepted.

I know what we tend to do with these posts is ignore them, however this is a really simple change that can hopefully make reviewing new users' posts much easier as we don't have to contend with poor answers posted on already answered questions.

Comment: The current system has a lot of nets to catch bad answers from new users. Furthermore, the lack of incentives (reputation) will make answering answered question even less attractive in the long run - we don't need to make it worse.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I find new users who answer questions that already have accepted answers

That's encouraged. New users may very well have newer information and a better answer.

> they tend to answer the questions quite poorly

We already have a process for bad answers (as well as a moderation queue for answers from new users). Downvotes and flagging. No need to do more with these.

> What I am suggesting, is a popup message

Right. Just one more thing for them to ignore.

Comment: +1 - There's nothing more we can possibly add information-wise to prevent a new user from crapping all over the site. ;)  At this point, we're down to community moderation to keep things clean and sparkly.

Comment: Fair enough.  Just another one of my crazy ideas.

Comment: @njallam - Not crazy. I simply disagree -I don't think adding a popup will add any value or that there is a particular problem that doesn't already have a solution.